# Controlling ggplot2 legend display order

Tags: r, ggplot2

Does anyone know how I can get control of the ordering of legends in ggplot2?

From what I can see the order appears related to the actual scale labels rather than the scale declaration order. Changing the scale titles alters the ordering. I've made a small example using the diamond dataset to highlight this. I'm trying to use ggplot2 for a series of plots and I want to make one variable appear on the right in them all. At present though this only happens in some of them, and I'm at a loss on how to enforce my desired ordering whilst retaining the appropriate scale labels.

```
library(ggplot2)
diamond.data <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ]
plot <- ggplot(diamond.data, aes(carat, price, colour = clarity, shape = cut)) +
  geom_point() + opts(legend.position = "top", legend.box = "horizontal")
plot # the legend will appear shape then colour 
plot + labs(colour = "A", shape = "B") # legend will be colour then shape
plot + labs(colour = "Clarity", shape = "Cut") # legend will be shape then colour
```

Comment: Related (though this question has a better solution): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035551/ordering-of-multiple-legends-guides-what-is-the-automatic-logic-how-to-change

Answer (score 158, accepted):

In 0.9.1, the rule for determining the order of the legends is **secret** and **unpredictable**.
Now, in 0.9.2, dev version in github, you can use the parameter for setting the order of legend.

Here is the example:

```
plot <- ggplot(diamond.data, aes(carat, price, colour = clarity, shape = cut)) +
  geom_point() + opts(legend.position = "top")

plot + guides(colour = guide_legend(order = 1), 
              shape = guide_legend(order = 2))
```

[image]

```
plot + guides(colour = guide_legend(order = 2), 
              shape = guide_legend(order = 1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 15):

It seems to me that the order of the legend is determined by the number of characters in the scale names. (Yes, I agree, that seems bizarre.)

So, a workaround is to pad your labels with spaces:

```
plot + labs(colour = "Clarity", shape = "      Cut")
```

[image]

---

I sincerely hope somebody posts a proper solution soon!

Comment: I get clarity then cut (padded with spaces) in my legend if I do what you did. packageDescription("ggplot2")$Version = 0.9.1

Comment: I should have made it clear that I actually want colour then shape (i.e. Clarity then Cut), not  Cut then Clarity akin to your example. However, I want to be able to name the scales anything and still have that ordering.

Comment: @Alastair It's now clear that my workaround will only work in `ggplot2` version 0.9.0 - this workaround no longer works in version 0.9.1. So, if you are still using 0.9.0 you can pad the strings with spaces to get your desired order.  As I said, it's a workaround only (and one with a limited shelf life).