# Avoid two-lined horizontal legend in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, line-breaks

How can I avoid the legend being broken into two lines in my horizontal legend?
Thanks a lot!

[image]

Comment: Don't know what you mean by "line break". It looks fine to me.

Comment: Thanks or your response! I would like the legend to be _single-lined_ not _two-lined_.

Comment: `+ guide_legend(nrow = 1)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Legend on bottom, two rows wrapped in ggplot2 in r](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27130610/legend-on-bottom-two-rows-wrapped-in-ggplot2-in-r)

Comment: Thanks for your responses

@Axeman
If I use 
`+ guide_legend(nrow = 1)` 
I get this error 
`Error in +guide_legend(nrow = 1) : invalid argument to unary operator` 

With 
`guides(fill=guide_legend(nrow=2,byrow=TRUE))` 
I get 
`Error in +guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)) + y_lab <- c(round(uws_data[1:9,  : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object`