# Legend in R: remove left space go to the line

Tags: r, legend

To explain my plots, I'm using the legend() function in R. The problem is that my explanations are long and thus take more than one line.
How to automatically go to the next line at the end of the line?
How to remove the left space between the left border and the beginning of the text?
Here is my script:

```
m <- matrix(c(1,2,3,3),nrow = 2,ncol = 2,byrow = TRUE) layout(mat = 
m,heights = c(0.5,0.5),widths=c(0.5,0.5))
par(mai=c(0.2,0.8,0.5,0.4)) plot(1:10,1:10)
par(mai=c(0.2,0.8,0.5,0.4)) plot(1:10,1:10)
par(mai=c(0,0,0,0)) plot.new()
legend(x="left","legend legend legend legend legend legend legend legend legendlegend legend legend legend legend legend legend legend legend legend legend legend legendlegend legend legend legend",cex=2)
```

Here is the plot:

[image]

Comment: See this question for help on inserting line breaks into your legend: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42281067/ggplot2-how-to-add-linebreak-to-horizontal-legend

Comment: Yes, but I want automatical line breaks

Answer (score 1):

In R with `"\n"` you go to the next line, you can split your long text with `strwrap` function and use `paste` like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/7367534/10263697.
With `legend(..., x.intersp = 0)` you remove the left space in the legend.

```
m <- matrix(c(1,2,3,3),nrow = 2,ncol = 2,byrow = TRUE) 
layout(mat = 
           m,heights = c(0.5,0.5),widths=c(0.5,0.5))
par(mai=c(0.2,0.8,0.5,0.4)) 
plot(1:10,1:10)
par(mai=c(0.2,0.8,0.5,0.4)) 
plot(1:10,1:10)
par(mai=c(0,0,0,0)) 
plot.new()
legend(x="left",paste(strwrap("legend legend legend legend legend legend legend legend legendlegend legend legend legend legend legend legend legend legend legend legend legend legendlegend legend legend legend", width = 0.3 * getOption("width")), sep = "\n")
,cex=2, x.intersp = 1)
```

Comment: with x.intersp=0, there is still a space between the left boarder of the box and the text.

Comment: Try with -1. Be careful because you may not see the points or lines of the legend. Maybe you're looking for `text` function