# How to get one line per scale / aes / guide when using legend.position = "bottom"

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am trying to make a plot with the legend at the bottom. I would like to get one line per `scale` i.e., one line with `am` and one line with `vs` (just like it displays if we use  `theme(legend.position = "left")` in the code below).

This might be very simple but I was not able to find the correct keywords or to understand correctly tutorials. Should it be done using `theme()` or `guides()`?

Thanks for advices or links towards the solution!

Here is an reprex:

This code has the legend at the bottom, as expected, but I can't figure out **how to have one line per `scale` (here color and shape)**:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = hp, color = as.factor(vs), shape = as.factor(am))) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_discrete(name = "vs") +
  scale_shape_discrete(name = "am") +
  guides(shape = guide_legend(title.position = "left", order = 1, nrow = 1),
         color = guide_legend(title.position = "left", order = 2, nrow = 1)) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

**When using `legend.position = "left"` (or `right)`, there is one line per scale:**

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = hp, color = as.factor(vs), shape = as.factor(am))) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_discrete(name = "vs") +
  scale_shape_discrete(name = "am") +
  guides(shape = guide_legend(title.position = "left", order = 1, nrow = 1),
         color = guide_legend(title.position = "left", order = 2, nrow = 1)) +
  theme(legend.position = "left")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, looking around I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60455371/10264278) post that solved the question by adding `legend.box="vertical"` argument to `theme()`.

**Note:** it seems that default arrangement of multiple legends has changed during `ggplot2` history; I found older posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11397958/10264278) where vertical arrangement with legend on top seems to be the default.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = hp, color = as.factor(vs), shape = as.factor(am))) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_discrete(name = "vs") +
  scale_shape_discrete(name = "am") +
  guides(shape = guide_legend(title.position = "left", order = 1, nrow = 1),
         color = guide_legend(title.position = "left", order = 2, nrow = 1)) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.box="vertical")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>