# How to restrict the ggplot legend rows (with guide_legend) when using ggpattern?

Tags: ggplot2, plot, ggpattern

I am trying to restrict the legend of a `ggplot` (with `ggpattern`) to 2 rows. It is more or less straightforward [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27131447/9096420) when you only have one aesthetic to play with. Additionally, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60455371/9096420) is a good example of how to manipulate legends with more than 1 aesthetic (e.g., shape AND color). Yet, `ggpattern` blends these into seemingly one aesthetic and the manipulation of the resulting legend isn't as straightforward.

Data and session info to reproduce at bottom.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpattern)

p0<-ggplot(Dat)+
  geom_col(
    aes(y=Prop,x=MHW,fill=Consumer),
    color="black",alpha=0.8
  )+
  facet_wrap(~Donor,nrow=2,scales="free")+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90),
    legend.position = "bottom"
  )+
  guides(
    fill = guide_legend(nrow = 2)
  )

png("Test0.png",width=12,height=9,units = "in",res=300,type = "cairo")
p0
dev.off()
```

As expected, the legend is in 2 rows:
[image]

Now let's change to ggpattern (changed rows indicated with `##`)

```
p1<-ggplot(Dat)+
  geom_col_pattern(                                  ##
    aes(y=Prop,x=MHW,fill=Consumer,
        pattern=Consumer,pattern_fill=Consumer),     ##
    color="black",alpha=0.8,
    pattern_key_scale_factor=.3                      ##
  )+
  facet_wrap(~Donor,nrow=2,scales="free")+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90),
    legend.position = "bottom"
  )+
  guides(
    # fill = guide_legend(nrow = 2),
    pattern_fill = guide_legend(nrow = 2)            ##
  )+
  scale_pattern_manual(                              ##
    values=c(rep(c('circle','stripe', 'crosshatch'),5)) ##
  ) 

png("Test1.png",width=12,height=9,units = "in",res=300,type = "cairo")
p1
dev.off()
```

[image]

Yet, now the legend isn't restricted to two rows. If you try just the `fill` aesthetic or both at the same time:

```
  guides(
    fill = guide_legend(nrow = 2),
    pattern_fill = guide_legend(nrow = 2) 
  )+
```

and

```
  guides(
    fill = guide_legend(nrow = 2) #,
    # pattern_fill = guide_legend(nrow = 2) 
  )+
```

neither help restrict the legend to two rows. How do I restrict the legend?

### Data

```
Dat<-structure(list(Detritus = c(195.378055295869, 195.378055295869, 
195.378055295869, 195.378055295869, 195.378055295869, 195.378055295869, 
195.378055295869, 195.378055295869, 195.378055295869, 195.378055295869, 
66.9513777221605, 66.9513777221605, 66.9513777221605, 66.9513777221605, 
66.9513777221605, 66.9513777221605, 66.9513777221605, 66.9513777221605, 
66.9513777221605, 66.9513777221605, 202.062496802138, 202.062496802138, 
202.062496802138, 202.062496802138, 202.062496802138, 202.062496802138, 
202.062496802138, 202.062496802138, 202.062496802138, 202.062496802138, 
1.10145527938025, 1.10145527938025, 1.10145527938025, 1.10145527938025, 
1.10145527938025, 1.10145527938025, 1.10145527938025, 1.10145527938025, 
1.10145527938025, 1.10145527938025, 0.095218385013956, 0.095218385013956, 
0.095218385013956, 0.095218385013956, 0.095218385013956, 0.095218385013956, 
0.095218385013956, 0.095218385013956, 0.095218385013956, 0.095218385013956, 
0.696299572709905, 0.696299572709905, 0.696299572709905, 0.696299572709905, 
0.696299572709905, 0.696299572709905, 0.696299572709905, 0.696299572709905, 
0.696299572709905, 0.696299572709905, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0.00476602121672308, 0.00476602121672308, 0.00476602121672308, 
0.00476602121672308, 0.00476602121672308, 0.00476602121672308, 
0.00476602121672308, 0.00476602121672308, 0.00476602121672308, 
0.00476602121672308, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 110.223171189265, 
110.223171189265, 110.223171189265, 110.223171189265, 110.223171189265, 
110.223171189265, 110.223171189265, 110.223171189265, 110.223171189265, 
110.223171189265, 0.054931677571981, 0.054931677571981, 0.054931677571981, 
0.054931677571981, 0.054931677571981, 0.054931677571981, 0.054931677571981, 
0.054931677571981, 0.054931677571981, 0.054931677571981, 0.000772862445925245, 
0.000772862445925245, 0.000772862445925245, 0.000772862445925245, 
0.000772862445925245, 0.000772862445925245, 0.000772862445925245, 
0.000772862445925245, 0.000772862445925245, 0.000772862445925245, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 329.312477609154, 329.312477609154, 
329.312477609154, 329.312477609154, 329.312477609154, 329.312477609154, 
329.312477609154, 329.312477609154, 329.312477609154, 329.312477609154, 
3.06883722794725, 3.06883722794725, 3.06883722794725, 3.06883722794725, 
3.06883722794725, 3.06883722794725, 3.06883722794725, 3.06883722794725, 
3.06883722794725, 3.06883722794725, 77.6283061274114, 77.6283061274114, 
77.6283061274114, 77.6283061274114, 77.6283061274114, 77.6283061274114, 
77.6283061274114, 77.6283061274114, 77.6283061274114, 77.6283061274114, 
0.276194323464863, 0.276194323464863, 0.276194323464863, 0.276194323464863, 
0.276194323464863, 0.276194323464863, 0.276194323464863, 0.276194323464863, 
0.276194323464863, 0.276194323464863, 0.647536119803539, 0.647536119803539, 
0.647536119803539, 0.647536119803539, 0.647536119803539, 0.647536119803539, 
0.647536119803539, 0.647536119803539, 0.647536119803539, 0.647536119803539, 
1.11133139200563, 1.11133139200563, 1.11133139200563, 1.11133139200563, 
1.11133139200563, 1.11133139200563, 1.11133139200563, 1.11133139200563, 
1.11133139200563, 1.11133139200563, 0.0268967426691688, 0.0268967426691688, 
0.0268967426691688, 0.0268967426691688, 0.0268967426691688, 0.0268967426691688, 
0.0268967426691688, 0.0268967426691688, 0.0268967426691688, 0.0268967426691688, 
0.622290423005387, 0.622290423005387, 0.622290423005387, 0.622290423005387, 
0.622290423005387, 0.622290423005387, 0.622290423005387, 0.622290423005387, 
0.622290423005387, 0.622290423005387, 0.359791910433618, 0.359791910433618, 
0.359791910433618, 0.359791910433618, 0.359791910433618, 0.359791910433618, 
0.359791910433618, 0.359791910433618, 0.359791910433618, 0.359791910433618, 
184.29970071925, 184.29970071925, 184.29970071925, 184.29970071925, 
184.29970071925, 184.29970071925, 184.29970071925, 184.29970071925, 
184.29970071925, 184.29970071925, 0.0146353418211845, 0.0146353418211845, 
0.0146353418211845, 0.0146353418211845, 0.0146353418211845, 0.0146353418211845, 
0.0146353418211845, 0.0146353418211845, 0.0146353418211845, 0.0146353418211845, 
0.000715875766578085, 0.000715875766578085, 0.000715875766578085, 
0.000715875766578085, 0.000715875766578085, 0.000715875766578085, 
0.000715875766578085, 0.000715875766578085, 0.000715875766578085, 
0.000715875766578085, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Fishery = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Consumer = c("Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", 
"Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", 
"Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Gelatinous", 
"Gelatinous", "Gelatinous", "Gelatinous", "Gelatinous", "Gelatinous", 
"Gelatinous", "Gelatinous", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Krill", "Krill", 
"Krill", "Krill", "Krill", "Krill", "Krill", "Krill", "Krill", 
"Forage Fish", "Forage Fish", "Forage Fish", "Forage Fish", "Forage Fish", 
"Forage Fish", "Forage Fish", "Forage Fish", "Forage Fish", "Forage Fish", 
"Misc. Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Misc. Fish", 
"Misc. Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Misc. Fish", 
"Juvenile Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Juvenile Fish", 
"Juvenile Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Juvenile Fish", 
"Juvenile Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Rockfish", "Rockfish", 
"Rockfish", "Rockfish", "Rockfish", "Rockfish", "Rockfish", "Rockfish", 
"Rockfish", "Jack Mackerel", "Jack Mackerel", "Jack Mackerel", 
"Jack Mackerel", "Jack Mackerel", "Jack Mackerel", "Jack Mackerel", 
"Jack Mackerel", "Jack Mackerel", "Jack Mackerel", "Hake", "Hake", 
"Hake", "Hake", "Hake", "Hake", "Hake", "Hake", "Hake", "Hake", 
"Benthic", "Benthic", "Benthic", "Benthic", "Benthic", "Benthic", 
"Benthic", "Benthic", "Benthic", "Benthic", "Seabirds", "Seabirds", 
"Seabirds", "Seabirds", "Seabirds", "Seabirds", "Seabirds", "Seabirds", 
"Seabirds", "Seabirds", "Mammals", "Mammals", "Mammals", "Mammals", 
"Mammals", "Mammals", "Mammals", "Mammals", "Mammals", "Mammals", 
"Fishery", "Fishery", "Fishery", "Fishery", "Fishery", "Fishery", 
"Fishery", "Fishery", "Fishery", "Fishery", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", 
"Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", 
"Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Gelatinous", 
"Gelatinous", "Gelatinous", "Gelatinous", "Gelatinous", "Gelatinous", 
"Gelatinous", "Gelatinous", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Krill", "Krill", 
"Krill", "Krill", "Krill", "Krill", "Krill", "Krill", "Krill", 
"Forage Fish", "Forage Fish", "Forage Fish", "Forage Fish", "Forage Fish", 
"Forage Fish", "Forage Fish", "Forage Fish", "Forage Fish", "Forage Fish", 
"Misc. Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Misc. Fish", 
"Misc. Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Misc. Fish", 
"Juvenile Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Juvenile Fish", 
"Juvenile Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Juvenile Fish", 
"Juvenile Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Rockfish", "Rockfish", 
"Rockfish", "Rockfish", "Rockfish", "Rockfish", "Rockfish", "Rockfish", 
"Rockfish", "Jack Mackerel", "Jack Mackerel", "Jack Mackerel", 
"Jack Mackerel", "Jack Mackerel", "Jack Mackerel", "Jack Mackerel", 
"Jack Mackerel", "Jack Mackerel", "Jack Mackerel", "Hake", "Hake", 
"Hake", "Hake", "Hake", "Hake", "Hake", "Hake", "Hake", "Hake", 
"Benthic", "Benthic", "Benthic", "Benthic", "Benthic", "Benthic", 
"Benthic", "Benthic", "Benthic", "Benthic", "Seabirds", "Seabirds", 
"Seabirds", "Seabirds", "Seabirds", "Seabirds", "Seabirds", "Seabirds", 
"Seabirds", "Seabirds", "Mammals", "Mammals", "Mammals", "Mammals", 
"Mammals", "Mammals", "Mammals", "Mammals", "Mammals", "Mammals", 
"Fishery", "Fishery", "Fishery", "Fishery", "Fishery", "Fishery", 
"Fishery", "Fishery", "Fishery", "Fishery"), Donor = c("Zooplankton", 
"Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Salmon", 
"Rockfish", "Hake", "Juvenile Fish", "Benthic", "Zooplankton", 
"Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Salmon", 
"Rockfish", "Hake", "Juvenile Fish", "Benthic", "Zooplankton", 
"Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Salmon", 
"Rockfish", "Hake", "Juvenile Fish", "Benthic", "Zooplankton", 
"Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Salmon", 
"Rockfish", "Hake", "Juvenile Fish", "Benthic", "Zooplankton", 
"Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Salmon", 
"Rockfish", "Hake", "Juvenile Fish", "Benthic", "Zooplankton", 
"Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Salmon", 
"Rockfish", "Hake", "Juvenile Fish", "Benthic", "Zooplankton", 
"Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Salmon", 
"Rockfish", "Hake", "Juvenile Fish", "Benthic", "Zooplankton", 
"Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Salmon", 
"Rockfish", "Hake", "Juvenile Fish", "Benthic", "Zooplankton", 
"Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Salmon", 
"Rockfish", "Hake", "Juvenile Fish", "Benthic", "Zooplankton", 
"Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Salmon", 
"Rockfish", "Hake", "Juvenile Fish", "Benthic", "Zooplankton", 
"Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Salmon", 
"Rockfish", "Hake", "Juvenile Fish", "Benthic", "Zooplankton", 
"Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Salmon", 
"Rockfish", "Hake", "Juvenile Fish", "Benthic", "Zooplankton", 
"Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Salmon", 
"Rockfish", "Hake", "Juvenile Fish", "Benthic", "Zooplankton", 
"Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Salmon", 
"Rockfish", "Hake", "Juvenile Fish", "Benthic", "Zooplankton", 
"Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Salmon", 
"Rockfish", "Hake", "Juvenile Fish", "Benthic", "Zooplankton", 
"Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Salmon", 
"Rockfish", "Hake", "Juvenile Fish", "Benthic", "Zooplankton", 
"Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Salmon", 
"Rockfish", "Hake", "Juvenile Fish", "Benthic", "Zooplankton", 
"Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Salmon", 
"Rockfish", "Hake", "Juvenile Fish", "Benthic", "Zooplankton", 
"Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Salmon", 
"Rockfish", "Hake", "Juvenile Fish", "Benthic", "Zooplankton", 
"Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Salmon", 
"Rockfish", "Hake", "Juvenile Fish", "Benthic", "Zooplankton", 
"Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Salmon", 
"Rockfish", "Hake", "Juvenile Fish", "Benthic", "Zooplankton", 
"Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Salmon", 
"Rockfish", "Hake", "Juvenile Fish", "Benthic", "Zooplankton", 
"Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Salmon", 
"Rockfish", "Hake", "Juvenile Fish", "Benthic", "Zooplankton", 
"Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Salmon", 
"Rockfish", "Hake", "Juvenile Fish", "Benthic", "Zooplankton", 
"Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Salmon", 
"Rockfish", "Hake", "Juvenile Fish", "Benthic", "Zooplankton", 
"Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Salmon", 
"Rockfish", "Hake", "Juvenile Fish", "Benthic"), Prop = c(1417.16886531397, 
21.8852589743467, 29.5205335617856, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.27731039677243, 
327.50830866045, 51.1400615337213, 5.29647698895142, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 432.093078201989, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 51.0494310878386, 
1.85177307192677, 53.6791923903298, 1.22426881699568, 0.447678212520347, 
0.0108188062979273, 0, 0, 0.712122477894116, 0.129836991126026, 
3.01381479489865, 0.429375380502875, 9.55847366160016, 6.55116783323041, 
0.840840438605795, 0.046249710322369, 0.322652592269059, 1.40659738778568, 
2.35895229863508, 5.69632701706482, 40.305644317743, 0.514963426130939, 
2.91947031365883, 0.121615077889678, 0.00907555165297567, 0.00073539519140489, 
0, 0, 1.22469472688476, 0.545024905072436, 2.04957719585246, 
0.0118268711741824, 3.20784444214808, 2.10466339517761, 0.485237400053026, 
0.0144050814181559, 0.153615511374632, 0.159524411882556, 0.414147440805842, 
0.519689856899177, 0.430867611693594, 0.00636979594256325, 1.60749793559994, 
0.537926031684436, 0, 0.00421928392766898, 0, 0, 0.135549144211162, 
0.0016863834068481, 2.90620227916775, 2.53134901312395, 35.6129076971812, 
12.0952219885951, 0.422734254350647, 0.0843215249443493, 0, 0, 
4.10550720195767, 1.91790098672496, 37.1197406894923, 0, 25.3967690693007, 
0.18826756476134, 0.0263827559709179, 0.00156361299544017, 0.00284374656952413, 
0, 0.732307567289515, 25.2546400500606, 0.368626704299541, 0.000420231357235188, 
0.120199285044128, 4.87345318075009, 0.124373759218538, 0.0313985827066985, 
0.0206980939802894, 0.0230888380542323, 0, 0.00109874331718929, 
0.478519185765927, 0.339160466140748, 1.49993377656359, 3.27450722365355, 
1.10728850131732, 0.0224745992469266, 0.17760410033594, 0.382116804399672, 
0.10544737536346, 0.34064263571257, 0, 0, 0, 0.561734361421642, 
0.262123906500932, 0, 0.0520197154380621, 3.63666569668098, 0, 
0.17085404555258, 1480.98880868256, 0.383980696580429, 36.6319663034093, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.11127300809657, 208.319040675764, 0.273992987508079, 
0.0891092907137129, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 215.954490957687, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 54.9286009257789, 0.469161558508563, 
49.7201823328684, 0.776011196128181, 0.460993201935953, 0.0138672177550104, 
0, 0, 1.68378528625113, 1.4659268303144, 4.09811728002028, 0.680189846947001, 
11.6133184499861, 7.92139441496285, 1.66589001872885, 0.0863688062908657, 
0.563271711372325, 1.7249508532637, 2.2469144494425, 7.49849908468619, 
55.3998578378037, 0.138117020761687, 3.76784428776134, 0.157589368848881, 
0.00192934846852898, 0.00103455463884516, 0, 0, 2.37768234206405, 
0.810825459331864, 3.45834639799013, 0.0846596910083975, 4.30189127867907, 
1.18438711744062, 0.758357275742268, 0.028135073209926, 0.270450419403965, 
0.190235699660435, 0.818734910162449, 1.00450088431345, 10.1271816346645, 
0.00965720383832612, 18.3577682768183, 3.36083127325828, 0.210530386674747, 
0.0969152790969377, 0.0176366626588672, 0.00344950826715526, 
0.702115148690833, 1.94932045096121, 6.41358861842098, 0.0325668049210667, 
24.1805699214855, 8.19422969521942, 0.339716093070585, 0.300324597784372, 
0, 0, 2.71099913452328, 3.14003215421284, 84.3060340111592, 0, 
46.9831368242163, 0.00351634488635138, 0.00995667063934028, 2.96446503412003e-08, 
0.0101229566324351, 0, 0.916063930481584, 58.6764716462903, 0.166829601836717, 
5.58184727333846e-05, 0.0755490452347125, 1.68692379472434, 0.0189872627761935, 
0.0288880616347642, 0.000946039170233896, 0.00767217984651186, 
0.076294623199603, 0.00057506209452, 0.5227132252172, 0.0619482744787457, 
1.84886149950565, 2.35514009373859, 0.884300572657665, 0.0419638868682333, 
0.128465917860897, 0.295031688941958, 0.12000517842897, 0.470381017621623, 
0, 0, 0, 0.0207034634950007, 0.214221943642372, 0, 0.0515155760949915, 
2.31093873862259, 0, 0.144893998318959), MHW = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("pre", "post"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-260L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

### Session Info

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_1.0.9     ggpattern_1.0.0 ggplot2_3.4.0   tidyr_1.2.0    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.8.3       pillar_1.7.0       compiler_4.2.2     class_7.3-20      
 [5] tools_4.2.2        memoise_2.0.1      lifecycle_1.0.3    tibble_3.1.7      
 [9] gtable_0.3.0       pkgconfig_2.0.3    rlang_1.0.6        DBI_1.1.2         
[13] cli_3.6.0          rstudioapi_0.13    gridpattern_1.0.1  fastmap_1.1.0     
[17] e1071_1.7-11       withr_2.5.0        generics_0.1.2     vctrs_0.5.1       
[21] classInt_0.4-7     grid_4.2.2         tidyselect_1.1.2   glue_1.6.2        
[25] sf_1.0-7           R6_2.5.1           fansi_1.0.3        purrr_0.3.4       
[29] farver_2.1.0       magrittr_2.0.3     units_0.8-0        scales_1.2.0      
[33] ellipsis_0.3.2     assertthat_0.2.1   colorspace_2.0-3   labeling_0.4.2    
[37] KernSmooth_2.23-20 utf8_1.2.2         proxy_0.4-27       munsell_0.5.0     
[41] cachem_1.0.6       crayon_1.5.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you've specified `fill` and `pattern_fill`, the only thing you are missing and the only thing you actually need to specify is `pattern` (although you won't get an error for including all three):

`guides(pattern = guide_legend(nrow = 2))+`

```
p2<-ggplot(Dat)+
  geom_col_pattern(
    aes(y=Prop,x=MHW,fill=Consumer,
        pattern=Consumer,pattern_fill=Consumer),
    color="black",alpha=0.8,
    pattern_key_scale_factor=.3
  )+
  facet_wrap(~Donor,nrow=2,scales="free")+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90),
    legend.position = "bottom"
  )+
  guides(
    pattern = guide_legend(nrow = 2)
  )+
  scale_pattern_manual(
    values=c(rep(c('circle','stripe', 'crosshatch'),5))
  ) 

png("Test2.png",width=12,height=9,units = "in",res=300,type = "cairo")
p2
dev.off()
```

[image]