# Prevent ggplot2 legend from reordering labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a column ("category") that is factored with a specific order (it should spell "order" in the legend).

For the plot, I'm using a different subset of the data for each layer. When merging the data back together for the legend the factor's order changes.

Any ideas on how to prevent this reordering?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# make some data
set.seed(12345)
count = 5
data = data.frame(
  location = LETTERS[1:count],
  o=runif(count), r=runif(count), d=runif(count), e=runif(count), R=runif(count)
)
data = data %>%
  arrange(o) %>%
  mutate(rank = 1:count) %>%
  gather('category', 'value', o:R)

# arrange the factor for category
# NOTICE THE ORDER HERE
data$category = factor(data$category, levels=c('o', 'r', 'd', 'e', 'R'))

# get subsets
subsetO = data %>% filter(category=='o')
subsetNotO = data %>% filter(category!='o')

# confirm that the subset has the same factor levels as the original
all(levels(subsetO$category) == levels(data$category))

ggplot(data = data, aes(x=location, fill=category)) +
  geom_bar(data = subsetO, aes(y=value), stat='identity', position='stack') +
  geom_bar(data = subsetNotO, aes(y=-value), stat='identity', position='stack')
```

[image]

**Edit:** I have in already re-factored the column (which is the solution in many of the supposed duplicates)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Controlling ggplot2 legend display order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393123/controlling-ggplot2-legend-display-order)

Comment: Both suggested duplicates appear to fail to reorder the factor or the data. That is not the issue here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To also provide an answer to your question, you can order the colours individually with a `scale_fill_discrete`.

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x=location, fill=category)) +
  geom_bar(data = subsetO, aes(y=value), stat='identity', position='stack') +
  geom_bar(data = subsetNotO, aes(y=-value), stat='identity', position='stack') + 
  scale_fill_discrete(breaks = data$category)
```

A lot of these kind of questions can be answered by reading the following website [Cookbook for R - Graphs](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/index.html)