# How to prevent ggplot2 from combining key glyphs?

Tags: r, ggplot2

ggplot2 combines glyphs for the same scale which leads to confusing behaviour when using `geom_hline` and `geom_vline` to show two perpendicular lines as the key glyph for each color contains a cross (`+`) rather than `|` or `-` in correspondence to that color. How to prevent ggplot from combining `-` and `|` key glyphs?

```
library(ggplot2)
means = as.data.frame(t(colMeans(mtcars)))

(
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = drat))
    + geom_point()
    + geom_hline(data = means, aes(color = 'average disp', yintercept = drat))
    + geom_vline(data = means, aes(color = 'average drat', xintercept = disp))
)
```

[image]

I tried setting `key_glyph` explicitly for both the `geom_vline` and `geom_hline` but it does not change anything.

Note: aside of the ease of interpretation, this is crucial for creating colorblind-friendly plots.

Comment: Great question. I notice adding `, show.legend = F` to one of the lines makes ggplot2 show only a single glyph twice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[As per this answer to the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65799746/7941188) (this was asked recently) - create a second scale. In the linked question you will also find a related GitHub issue, [here for your convenience](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2483).

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)
means = as.data.frame(t(colMeans(mtcars)))

  ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = drat))+
    geom_point()+
    geom_hline(data = means, aes(color = 'average disp', yintercept = drat))+
    scale_color_manual(values = "red", name = NULL) +
    new_scale_color() +
    geom_vline(data = means, aes(color = 'average drat', xintercept = disp)) +
    scale_color_manual(values = "blue", name = NULL)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-02-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, this is a great solution indeed. I confirmed this one as a duplicate of the other. It is surprising to me that the SO question wizard did not pick it up and humbling to see that I could not find it.

Comment: @krassowski PS you’ve asked a good question +1. I find duplicates in those cases a really good and important thing, as it helps broadening search terms. I don’t think I would have found the other question myself. it might not even have been indexed because so fresh. I find it also kind of cool how this particular question was asked just so close to one another twice. And maybe even more often, difficult to know.

Answer (score 6):

Possible hacks off the top of my mind:

1. Disguise a shape legend (with horizontal & vertical lines) as a colour legend (pro: less manual work than the following approaches; con: difficult to map the shape aesthetic to anything else)
2. Convert the ggplot2 object to a grob object via `ggplotGrob`, & remove the offending grobs for horizontal / vertical line segments there (pro: doesn't affect any other aesthetic or require other packages; con: require familiarity with grob modifications & manual work for each plot)
3. Create separate plots with only the desired legend items, then combine the legends together using one of the many available packages such as `patchwork` or `cowplot` (pro: can deal with any combination of desired legend; con: require familiarity with other packages + manual labour to tweak the plots' appearances)

I haven't looked into modifying the underlying ggplot code itself just yet, because I feel that under most circumstances, combining glyphs is a desirable end. Legend for horizontal *and* vertical lines is a valid exception, but not a particularly common one. So I'd go with hacks for now.

Demonstration for the first hack below:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = drat)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_hline(data = means, aes(color = 'average disp', yintercept = drat),
             show.legend = F) +
  geom_vline(data = means, aes(color = 'average drat', xintercept = disp),
             show.legend = F) +
  geom_point(data = data.frame(val = c(means$drat, means$disp), 
                               name = c("average disp", "average drat")),
             aes(x = 150, y = 3, # arbitrary values, anything within the plot's range
                 color = name, shape = name),
             alpha = 0,          # don't actually show the point in the plot
             size = 5,           # adjust size / stroke to suit your plot's size
             stroke = 2) +
  scale_shape_manual(name = "colour",
                     values = c("average disp" = "\U2014", # horizontal line
                                "average drat" = "\U007C"),# vertical line
                     guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 1)))
```

[image: result]

Comment: Z.Lin, would you mind adding this as an answer to the (duplicately related) question as per above?